# Side by side subtitles

Tags: 3d, video-player, subtitle

Is there a video player in Linux that can display subtitles from a srt file correctly for side by side 3D video?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Bino. It can display the videos in even/odd rows (or other options for different 3D displays) so you don't actually need to set the display to 3D mode, and it can display subtitles. At least... it supposedly can show subtitles, I can't seem to get a .srt file working with it at the moment, but it shows options for subtitle display.